# uploading files atomically to both Firebase Storage and Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Using swift, I would like to upload an array of images to Firebase Storage, retrieve the URLs, then upload this along with some other data to Firebase Database. How do I ensure that the entire upload process is all or nothing (atomic), as it would be a real problem if the upload was interrupted and the images were in the Storage but the URLs weren't in the database.

More specifically, Firebase Database allows you to do simultaneous atomic updates to multiple locations *within* the Database using `updateChildValues`. Is there any way of making this span both Database and Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no atomic updates across systems like you're suggesting.  Realtime Database and Storage are completely different systems.  You have to manage all the error cases for the sequence of work on your own.

If an upload to Storage is interrupted and incomplete, you don't have to worry about partial files existing in the storage bucket.

If you want to reduce the amount of risk for something going wrong, consider using [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to move some of the work to a managed backend so that the client doesn't have to be responsible for so many things.